# TextColor not showing when row backgroundcolor set

Tags: android

If my row is colored red the text won't set to green and bold italic. When debugging I can see it telling the TextView to set each textViews setting.

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            String[] items = list.get(l).split(":");
            for(int i=0; i < items.length; i++){
                //see if i need to colour row
                if(items[i].startsWith("colorme_") == true) {
                    if (items[i].substring(8).equals("red") == true) {
                        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                } else { 
                    //create a temp textview then add to row
                    TextView tempTV = new TextView(getContext());
                    tempTV.setText(items[i].toString());
                    //test against correct answers and colour text view green if correct
                    if (correctAnswers != null && correctAnswers.size() > i) {
                        if (correctAnswers.get(i).equals(items[i].toString()) == true) {
                            tempTV.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            tempTV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                        }                               
                    }
                    row.addView(tempTV,lpTextView); 
                }
            }
            //add the row
            tempTable.addView(row);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you have separated the two different color setting codes on different sides on an `if else` so they won't both get called at the same time, because if the `if` statement returns true, then the else statement will not be triggered and you will pass the `setTextColor` code without running it and vice versa, if the if statement returns false, then you will skip changing the background color and only change the text color.

Hope that makes sense

Edit here is an example

```
if(items[i].startsWith("colorme_") == true) {
    //this is where your are preforming your change row color to red
} else{
    //this is where you are setting your text color to green
}
```

Comment: it is only calling that if the item[i] which is the first in the list starts with "colorme". this is working and my text is appearing in the row and the row is being colored red... just the text doesn't change. debugging is showing it going throw and setting the textview's text color. Thanks

Comment: Look at my edit (and can you format that as code please, I am having trouble doing that at this moment)

Comment: thanks i have put in the edit request... so by coloring and setting the table rows background i can't set the individual textviews that are created with the rest of the loop? it is going through the creation of text views as they are appearing on my row

Comment: If you removed the `else` from that statement, then both the text color and the row color could be changed

Comment: thanks for your help with this. i worked out that it was pushing the i because of the loop etc. feel a bit silly but you answer helped. Thanks